# new nodes in docker swarm to ensure failover

Tags: azure, docker, docker-swarm, azure-virtual-machine, docker-machine

How many more masters or workers or both should be added in a swarm having 3 physical nodes (1 master, 2 workers, master also serving as worker) to ensure system-failover managed by Docker ?

Is it recommended to add Azure VMs as new nodes in such a swarm ?

Comment: I think you should make your 3 nodes to 2 masters. as if you have 1 leader (the manager) if it fails the 2 workers wont know what to do. the containers that were on the master will not start again. having 3 masters solves it.

Comment: @BatchenRegev, as per following link, 2 masters on 3 nodes swarm are not recommonded. What do you suggest ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527906/docker-swarm-multiple-managers-and-workers-vs

Comment: Sorry i meant - make all your 3 nodes as managers.  3 managers. i have it also and it works and also if one fails it continue to work. ( idk why i wrote 2 masters, sorry)